# Help me to understand correctly this sentence "She sounded very eager to meet you."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

when someone says "She sounded very eager to meet you." it means that

> She said exactly "I'm really eager to meet him" (him refer to me).

or

> Her saying or expression implied that she really wants to meet me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***If*** she had said exactly

> I'm really eager to meet him.

Then the report would have been

> She *said* she is really eager to meet you.

But since the report was

> She *sounded* very eager to meet you.

then she might have made remarks like

> That guy is datable.
>
> That guy was really interesting. Where can I find him?
>
> Is that guy a regular here? If so, I'll be back.

and so on.